# Using mouse selection tool on the desktop is very laggy - Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04

Whenever I select stuff from the desktop with my mouse, gnome-shell process seems to use way more cpu than the usual and it becomes very laggy.

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 with Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Here's an example I recorded:
https://vimeo.com/331242235

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I was unable to find anything in logs. The same thing with Wayland or Xorg, so it must be Gnome/nautilus related. 

I do not experience video issues with other programs.
_Edit_: definitely gnome related, as it doesn't lag in regular `nautilus --browser` window.